# Setting values to parameters in a constructor in Java

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

I just wanted to ask basically what the title says. Here's my example and I want x to be the new set random. I also am doing this off a phone switch doesn't support an equal sign so - means equal. Also the bracket is (. So when I do 
Constructor a - new Constructor(x)

```
public class Opponent (

    public static x - 0;

    public Opponent (int value) (
        value - 5;
    )

    public static void main (String() args) (
        Opponent character1 - new Opponent(x)
        System.out.println(x);
    )
)
```

Basically I want x to become 5. The game I am developing concerns randomization then the values should give them to the parameter to the newly created character.

Problem I am having is that its not working which means it probably can't do this.

Is there anyway I can do this.

I apologize if it is a dumb question though but anyways thanks.

Comment: First of all, you need brackets `{ }` not parenthesis

Comment: And `=` instead of `-`

Comment: This is very basic stuff. Not only your question, but the syntax for anything you wrote. Please, look up some tutorials and learn some givens before you ask a question like this.

Comment: Yep, the correct answer to this question: you will want to study a decent Java text or two. It's how I (and many others) started in this language, and if it worked well for us, it will work well for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Opponent {

    public static int x = 0;

    public Opponent (int value) {
        x = value;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int y = 5; // random number I chose to be 5
        Opponent character1 = new Opponent(y);
        System.out.println(character1.x + ""); // will display 5 (which was int y)
    }
}
```

**List of Problems:**

• To open/close a method/class, **don't use** `(` and `)`; you have to use `{` and `}`

• `public static void main (String() args)` needs to be
 `public static void main (String[] args)`

• To initialize something, use `=`, **not** `-`.

• You need to give `x` a type, such as `int`.

• When you defined `Opponent character1 - new Opponent(x)`, you need to have a semi-colon at the end.

• You passed x as a parameter in the line `Opponent character1 = new Opponent(y);`, even though you were trying to define `x` *with* the parameter. Give it a different value.

---

One note: why would you define an instance of the class *in* the class? Instead of using this:

```
Opponent character1 = new Opponent(y);
System.out.println(character1.x + "");
```

You could just write this:

```
System.out.println(Opponent.x + "");
```

However, you could create `character1` if you were accessing class `Opponent` from a different class.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know what your question is, but try running this:

```
public class Opponent {

    public int x;

    public Opponent (int value) {
        x = value;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Opponent character1 = new Opponent(5);
        System.out.println(character1.x); // this will output: 5
    }
}
```

A few problems with your question:

1. you are trying to initialize a static variable thinking its an instance variable?
2. x is not initialized in main()
3. value is not defined as a field in Opponent

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Like I said though that I am typing from a phone and cannot use most symbols.

Answer (score -1):

maybe something like this. i leave the [random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java) up to you:

```
public class Opponent
{
    private int score;

    public Opponent()
    {
        // you probbaly want to override this with
        // a random number generator
        this.score = 0;
    }

    public Opponent(int value)
    {
        this.score = value;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Opponent character1 = new Opponent();
        Opponent character2 = new Opponent(5);

        int result = character1.getScore() - character2.getScore();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```